An old cartoon from the 2000s or more that features a group of teens searching for a green stone that can teleport them
It was on a now deleted channel with the number 7, I believe, in the logo.  The title was something like "The Green Stone" or the "Blue Stone". In any case the stone was green but I don't remember if there was a reason it was that color.

In what country did you watch it? Were the kids Caucasian? Asian? African? Did it seem like it had been dubbed over?

Slash:// had a bunch of teens traveling through the world wide web courtesy of a magical green stone.

Where did you watch this? Many countries have channels numbered 7
